# How to insert a separator Frame between two other Frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to separate two frames with a third one, which should look like a vertical line. Using pack manager it always shows up on the very left or right, no matter how I shuffle the order of packing and/or `side` as `'left'` or `'right'`. When I use grid it doesn't show at all. Below is my code:
**EDIT:**

I added Import/Export Section definition, so the code is complete working example.

```
class ImportSection(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.lbl_import = tk.Label(self, text='IMPORT', width=20)
        self.lbl_import.grid()


class ExportSection(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.lbl_export = tk.Label(self, text='EXPORT', width=20)
        self.lbl_export.grid()

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.import_section = ImportSection(self)
        self.export_section = ExportSection(self)
        self.sep = tk.Frame(width=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')

        # I tried to shuffle the order and experimented with left/right with no luck.
        # the line is always on the very right or left
        # self.import_section.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, anchor='n')
        # self.export_section.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, anchor='n')
        # self.sep.pack(side='left', fill='y', padx=5, pady=5)

        # another attempt with grid, but the line does not show at all
        self.import_section.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='n')
        self.sep.grid(           row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ns')
        self.export_section.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    # app.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True) - I used this version with pack
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: add all the modules imported please, and function definitions for user-defined functions.

Comment: I didn't want to paste too much code, just limit to the relevant part. `ImportSection` and `ExportSection` are Frames that contain few buttons. So the strange behaviour that I see is that the vertical line is never placed between those two frames, but on left/right (commented code with pack) or not displayed at (with grid). I will edit the question to add those two classes, so that the code example is complete and can be run.

Comment: You don't put the separator in the same Frame as the `ImportSection` and `ExportSection` because you don't specify the parent. Therefore, it is put in the root window. That's why `pack` doesn't work (`self.sep` is already put into `root` with `grid`) and why it's not between the two other frames. Change `self.sep = tk.Frame(width=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')` to `self.sep = tk.Frame(self, width=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')`.

Comment: eeeh, I missed the `self`... This would be an accepted answer if you post it.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the frame you are trying to use as separator is not in the same frame as the `ImportSection` and `ExportSection` because you don't specify its parent. When you don't specify a parent, tkinter will make the widget a child of the root window. This is also the reason why you can't `pack` `app` into the root window: `self.sep` is already put into root with `grid`.

Change

```
self.sep = tk.Frame(width=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')
```

to

```
self.sep = tk.Frame(self, width=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can maybe use ttk.Separator:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.import_section = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Canvas(self.import_section, width=200, height=400, bg='cyan').grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.export_section = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Canvas(self.export_section, width=200, height=400, bg='lightgreen').grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.sep = ttk.Separator(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        self.import_section.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='n')
        self.sep.grid(           row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ns')
        self.export_section.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into the `ttk.Separator`, but what I'm really interested to see is why the code I posted is not working, not how to draw the vertical line, which can be probably done in many ways.